# 5v contact closure SSR?

Tags: solid-state-relay

I want to have a contact open/closed when a USB port is powered on or off. When monitoring the USB port with a multimeter it takes >1 minute for the voltage to drop from 5v to zero. What is a simple circuit (or single component) that will close and open (in <1 second) a contact when the USB port is outputting 5v and draw minimal current while operating?

Comment: You want the contact *closed* (conducting) when the USB port is *off*?

Comment: I don't care if it is normally open or closed when off (being open when off makes more 'sense' to me)..

Comment: Do you need this detection on the device side of the USB connection (i.e. on the part that gets unplugged)? Or on the host computer side of the connection? Or placed somehow in between the two but independent of the two?

Comment: I want to know if there is power available on the device side.

Comment: What is the this contact going to be connected to? That will determine the type of SSR or whatever. What is "minimal current"? 1uA 1mA 10mA 100mA? Your meter is probably drawing less than 1uA, so drawing a few mA will make the 1 minute go away.

Comment: The contact will have a small current <10uA, but I do not have the specs of the actual circuit. No more than 100mA to keep the contact open or closed if possible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple optoisolator if the current is < 10uA and DC less than 50V.

For example, a  [TLP620(F)](http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Toshiba%20PDFs/TLP620%28-2,-4%29.pdf).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJhH02.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R2 is probably not necessary, but if necessary it might help it switch faster. Chances are you only need R1 and the optoisolator. The circuit draws about 10mA without R2, and 15mA with R2.

This circuit provides "galvanic isolation" so if there happens to be a few volts between the USB host and whatever you are connecting the "contact" to, nothing unfortunate will happen.

Comment: Forgot to specify: The 'perfect' solution would fit inside the USB connector, but I will order these parts to make the circuit.

Comment: There are smaller optoisolators. Lots that will easily fit into a dongle housing. You can get quite a bit of stuff into a small dongle.

Comment: Is an SMD the best option to fit a dongle?  Could you spec one that I could get from Newark??

Comment: @shaun5 Almost any similar type would work. TLP291 is available from Digikey.

Comment: How do I calculate the required value of R1 for this simple circuit?  I 'assume' R2 doesn't change and is only there to draw current to discharge the power supply.  I am an ME not EE...

Comment: If the current from (5V-1.25V)/R1 multiplied by the CTR (at that current) is much greater (a factor of 4 is probably safe enough) than the current your "contact" requires, you're okay. The TLP291(GB-TP,E) is 100% at 5mA, so 390 ohms give you almost 10mA, so up to 2mA should be okay on the other side. You could safely double the resistor (and halve the current to 5mA) with that good an opto, but 10mA is not a lot of current.

Comment: In general for this sort of thing, to optimize for a volume design, you would have to iterate, as the CTR changes by current and by model type, to find the optimal part number for cost/availability/minimum current/reliability, but as this one meets all the stated requirements, I think it's enough.

Answer (score 2):

These are quite small relays that operate at 5V and take about 30mA of current: -

[image]

At 5V the coil current will be 28mA. It has a single, normally open contact.